# VBA IE for mapping multiple directions http://gebweb.net/optimap/

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I am very new to VBA IE.  For my job I must visit multiple addresses. I found a website that allows you to add as many as you need and give you directions.  The website is http://gebweb.net/optimap/    Here is what I want to do if possible. In column A1 I have it listed as my starting point.  In column A2 is my starting address. From column A3 to as many rows as I would need for the addresses I am visiting  (step1) have the macro copy all in column A2 until the last cell in that column that has an address.  (step2) open up website http://gebweb.net/optimap/  (step3) click on Bulk add by address or (lat, lng). (step4) paste all copied addresses from column A into the empty block on website. (step5) click on add list of locations on website. (step6) click on calculate fastest roundtrip.  (step7) Print the current page because this will give me the map as well as the turn by turn directions. Thank you all for your help.  This would save me much time throughout the day.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this.

```
Sub Maps()


Dim sXMLURL As String
'Me.Text1.SetFocus
sXMLURL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=" & Range("A1").Value & "&destinations="
'Me.Text2.SetFocus
sXMLURL = sXMLURL & Range("A2").Value & "&mode=driving&language=en-US&units=imperial&sensor=false"

Dim objXMLHTTP As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
Set objXMLHTTP = New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60

With objXMLHTTP
    .Open "GET", sXMLURL, False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-URLEncoded"
    .send
End With

'Debug.Print objXMLHTTP.responseText

Dim domResponse As DOMDocument60
Set domResponse = New DOMDocument60
domResponse.LoadXML objXMLHTTP.responseText
Dim ixnStatus
Set ixnStatus = domResponse.SelectSingleNode("//status")

'Debug.Print ixnStatus.Text

If ixnStatus.Text = "OK" Then
    Dim ixnDistance, ixnDuration
    Set ixnDistance = domResponse.SelectSingleNode("/DistanceMatrixResponse/row/element/distance/text")
    Set ixnDuration = domResponse.SelectSingleNode("/DistanceMatrixResponse/row/element/duration/text")
    'Debug.Print "Distance: " & ixnDistance.Text
    'Debug.Print "Duration: " & ixnDuration.Text
    Range("B1").Value = ixnDistance.Text
    Range("B2").Value = ixnDuration.Text
End If

'Me.Command0.SetFocus

Set domResponse = Nothing
Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: ryguy7272,  thank you for your help.  I do apologize for some reason my first thank you never posted a long time ago.  Thank you again

Comment: Please mark the answer as useful if it helped.  Thanks!